# How to print on Oracle SQL Developer console using SQLJ

Tags: java, oracle, sqlj, oracle-sqldeveloper

I created and launch the SQLJ Java procedure (using SQL Developer). I have some bugs and I would like to debug Java source code. What is the best way to do this? Is it possible to print to the SQL Developer console some information using System.out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default standard output device in the Oracle Java virtual machine (JVM) is the current trace file.

If you want to reroute all standard output from a program executing in the server--output from any `System.out.println()` calls, for example--to a user screen, you can execute the [SET_OUTPUT()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e10588/appendixa.htm#autoId8) procedure of the [DBMS_JAVA](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e10588/appendixa.htm#JJDEV13000) package as in the following example.

Input the buffer size in bytes (10,000 bytes in this case).

```
sqlplus> execute dbms_java.set_output(10000);
```

Output exceeding the buffer size will be lost.

If you want your code executing in the server to expressly output to the user screen, you can also use the PL-SQL **DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()** [3](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_output.htm#ARPLS67327) procedure instead of the Java `System.out.println()` method.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Developer has a built-in PL/SQL debugger.  There is a useful guide on how to use it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/obe/sqldev_obe/plsql_debug/plsql_debug.htm#t5).  Pay special attention to the need for DEBUG CONNECT SESSION and DEBUG ANY PROCEDURE privileges.

I admit I don't know whether this works for SQLJ but it seems like the best place to start.